# Writing a CV for teaching job

Tags: resume, new-job

So, I have been trying to write a CV, I graduated recently so I do not have much work experience, and I want your help with somethings. I am mostly applying for a teaching job and for scholarship to continue my studies.

1- I worked as a private tutor, like self-employed, collecting groups of students and teaching them in their homes or in classes. Should I add this to my CV? if yes how can I add it?

2- I have enrolled in a lot of online classes (Coursera for example) I know I should add this in "Course" section, but how can I add that? Is the course description needed?

At the end, any other advice to improve my CV can be helpful!!

Thank you all.

Comment: 1 seems more or less obvious to me: add it as it is relevant experience (except you have some reason not to: the teaching was illegal, you taught something what is not allowed to teach in your country etc.) 2 depends on the classes: are they relevant to the job or not? Is the person you are applying to open to coursera learning or not? I wouldn't add "general" videos, just does.who are relevant to the job.

Comment: One thing to definitely look at is using a spell checker and Capitalising where necessary

Answer (score 1):

> So, I have been trying to write a CV, I graduated recently so I do not
> have much work experience,

Contact your school and see if they have an office that helps graduates find jobs. Many do have an office and they will even work with recent graduates. The office could be in your department, or your college, or even a central office.

The school wants their graduates to find jobs. They may have other job search services. They may even allow you to attend a job fair.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this doesn't answer the question... OP is not asking about how/where to look for jobs, but about what to put as relevant experience/studies in their CV.